# Taking a clone of a customized RHEL server hosted in a data center remotely

Tags: linux, rhel, cloning

We are planning to upgrade OS to RHEL 6.6 on all our servers. All our servers are located in a data center. We have to follow a repeated process of installing application stack, securing, hardening etc on all the servers.

Is there a automated approach for this which we can do remotely ? We asked the data center team if they can take a clone and deploy the image but they would not do that.

Comment: What about puppet?

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat's own [Kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Installation_Guide/#ch-kickstart2) is a popular approach for automating RHEL installs/upgrades.  It can be used to perform the OS install/upgrade itself and then to perform [post-install/upgrade](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Installation_Guide/#s1-kickstart2-postinstallconfig) actions such as hardening and installing further packages.

Comment: Can we do this remotely without the help of data center personnel ? Another thing is we only have ssh access to the server.

Comment: Only having ssh access to the server makes Kickstart approach tricky/unrealistic.  Why not just write your own set of RPMs and scripts to install the application stack and do the hardening?